# Cannot Connect to Plesk v12 SQL Server Remotely from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, plesk

I am difficult to understand why the [mssql.anggalisdiyanto.net](http://mssql.anggalisdiyanto.net) domain is can be accessed and i can login successfully from ASP.NET Enterprise Manager via browser, but not from SQL Server Management Studio. It is error like in below figure :

[image: Error login SQL Server remotely]

Help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is MSSQL instance name you are using?

If you don't specify instance name and connect like "server.com" than default instance name is used "MSSQLSERVER", but instance name of your MSSQL server may be "MSSQLSERVER2012" or "SQLEXPRESS" and in this case you should connect like "server.com\MSSQLSERVER2012" or "server.com\SQLEXPRESS"

You can check instance name in "SQL server configuration manager":
[image: plesk MS SQL server]

In case instance name is OK, check that remote network connections are "Enabled" for specified IP addresses(but pay attention to security threats):
[image: Plesk remote connect to MS SQL server]

**Security Note**

When you allow remote connections to MS SQL server it means that SQL server *will* be open for password brute force attacks, Denied of Service(DoS) attacks, any kinds of exploit attacks.

All this kinds of attacks may slowdown whole your server.

Comment: Thanks, so it become 'mssql.anggalisdiyanto.net/SQLEXPRESS'? I am waiting an email reply from my technician for their SQL Instance name.

Comment: Yes, Angga, if your instance name is "SQLEXPRESS". Also you may by command "nslookup mssql.anggalisdiyanto.net" that this hostname actually can be resolved. Anyway you can change it to "anggalisdiyanto.net\SQLEXPRESS" <-- not that "\" should be used instead of "/"