# Remote access to SQL with plesk sql server

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, plesk

I am trying to connect sql remotely from my SSMS to plesk database but couldn't connect.

You can see my server details in[image]

I changed access control to `Allow remote connections from any host` but still not allow me to connect. I know we need to apply network rule and i did it on my local network for sql server but dont know how to apply it on plesk, i did RND for this but didn't got proper solution.

Comment: Could you please try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31448583/1592008

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin Thanks, but i dont have plesk RDP i am just connecting through live IP of plesk in browser, There how we can do this ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's can't be done from Plesk UI.